# Some problems with decorators for classmethods

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, class-method

I have some piece of code in which I want to use a decorator on a `classmethod` as follows:

```
import functools

def mydeco(function):
    @classmethod
    def wrapper(cls):
        return function(cls) 
    return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, function)
    # return wrapper

class BaseClass(object):
    @classmethod
    @mydeco
    def foo(cls):
        return "42" 

print BaseClass.foo()
```

When I comment out the line `@mydeco` the code works, i.e. the text `42` is printed. When including this decorator I have several problems:

- When using the simpler line `return wrapper` I get the error

  ```
  TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
  ```

How to do it right, i.e. that, in the given example, the original function is returned without being altered.

- When using the more complex call `return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, function)` to preserve some of the original function attributed I get the error

  ```
  AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute '__module__'
  ```

I am not sure if this error is related to the first issue, but it looks a different issue to me. Any specific suggestions to solve these issues are welcome.

The above example does not really 'do' something, it is merely the smallest possible example to show the problem I have.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What output are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Just the same output. The example does not really 'do' something yet, I just want to get it to run (so I can actually 'do' something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason this will not work for you?

```
import functools

def mydeco(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return function(*args, **kwargs) 
    return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, function)

class BaseClass(object):
    @classmethod
    @mydeco
    def foo(cls):
        return "42" 

print BaseClass.foo()
42
```

Comment: This finally seems to work. Interesting to note the order of the decorators are of importance.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw an [interesting post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/how-you-implemented-your-python.html) on decorators, here's the explanation but it doesn't provide a work around.

> when the decorator is applied around @classmethod or @staticmethod, it can fail with an exception. This is because the wrappers created by these, do not have some of the attributes being copied.

I neither know how to correctly decorate a static/class method, but when I encounter similar exceptions I'll do one of the following just to get my code working without any insight:

- change order of @mydeco and @staticmethod
- discard @staticmethod

#### update

Here's another [great post](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/blob/master/blog/02-the-interaction-between-decorators-and-descriptors.md) on how to correctly implement descriptors

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the problem is in the `@classmethod` before `def wrapper...` (as `mydeco` is a function definition not a class definition)

Comment: Your answer is not really helpful, as it does not fix my problem. I can see your concern, but I know for sure that it works this way (in a bigger context impossible to post here).

Comment: So, you don't post an idea of "your bigger context", I try to help you and I get a '-1'? Ok, man.

Anyway, use "@classmethod" on a "method" of a "class", please. Take a look at "cmd"'s response. He/She also removes "@classmethod" before "def wrapper...", as I pointed at before.

Answer (score -3):

```
from functools import wraps

def mydeco(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Calling Decorated Function"
        return function(*args, **kwargs) 
    #return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper(function), function)
    return wrapper


@mydeco
class BaseClass():
    def foo(self, cls):
        return "42" 

a = BaseClass()
print a.foo(22)
```

it works now

Comment: This is not a correct answer. The function `foo` has to be a classmethod which is not the case in your example. And the decorator has to be ONLY on foo, not the whole class. Also, does this implementation perserve function attributes, as with `update_wrapper`?